# Is it possible to declare local anonymous structs in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust

Sometimes I like to group related variables in a function, without declaring a new struct type.

In C this can be done, e.g.:

```
void my_function() {    
    struct {
        int x, y;
        size_t size;
    } foo = {1, 1, 0};
    // ....
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Rust? If not, what would be the closest equivalent?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

While **anonymous** structs aren't supported, you can scope them locally, to do almost exactly as you've described in the C version:

```
fn main() {

    struct Example<'a> {
        name: &'a str
    };

    let obj = Example { name: "Simon" };
    let obj2 = Example { name: "ideasman42" };

    println!("{}", obj.name); // Simon
    println!("{}", obj2.name); // ideasman42
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1444f7a017148d77adb4062558f038db&version=stable&backtrace=0)

One other option is a tuple:

```
fn main() {

    let obj = (1, 0, 1);

    println!("{}", obj.0);
    println!("{}", obj.1);
    println!("{}", obj.2);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=38e49c50b6d83ebc29019093eba73c2c&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: I find this very strange. The syntax exists for tuples and arrays, why not structs? I feel like I should be able to do `let pos = { x: 10, y: 42 }`. It's basically just a tuple with named fields.

Comment: @BrandonDyer Rust doesn't have built-in support for this syntax, but there is [a macro](https://crates.io/crates/structx/0.1.5) that implements it.